# How do I emulate the scenario when rabbitmq sends a NEGATIVE delivery confirmation?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, queue

I am looking into retry logic in Python where rabbitmq gives negative confirmation (nack) when published a message. I want to create this scenario where publishing to queue returns `nack`. I am fairly new to rabbit and have no idea how can I do this. I am using python pika to deal with rabbit. It would be great if you can give some ideas and solutions!

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the queue process with rabbitmqctl as described [here](https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/I_oFeiOria4/m/tNyJaRDICfEJ).